# Meteor package for upload on amazon s3

Tags: meteor

1. Which package to use for file uploads to amazon S3 ? knox or collectionFS or any other ?
   Is `collectionFs` ready for file uploads to S3? Or `knox` is good enough?

Note: in any case i don't want to share my key on the client side. Because of security issue.

2 . Also is there a option where the client file stream can be directly conected to a stream to upload on S3. File is not actually present on the server at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be looking at this too. CollectionF5 allows file to be send to the server and you can create a handler that sends it to s3 (possibly as blob stream and not a storage). https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-s3

In the end, you need a place to specify the access key for uploading. If you do not put it in the client side, and you wish the file stream to directory upload on s3, how does the stream get the access?
Possibly you could also take a look at this as alternative: https://www.inkfilepicker.com/